# Spring doesn't load custom css

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with my spring boot application.
It seems that it doesn't load the custom css file.
I put it under *resources/static/css*, I also tried under *resources/public/css* but it doesn't work too.

I leave you my project on git hub account so you can check what is wrong

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/StefanoPisano/expenses)

Also, when I open the login page under the console of chrome there is a warning

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8080/css/style.css".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `MonthlyExpensesController` which contains the following code:

```
@RestController("/monthly")
public class MonthlyExpensesController {

    @GetMapping()
    public Expenses getMonthlyExpenses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your error is that you try to set the path */monthly* for the controller with the value of the annotation. But the value of the `@RestController` annotation ist used as a bean name and not for path resolution.

Therefore your `MonthlyExpensesController` is registered for the default path. It is found as a controller to handle */css/style.css* and returns `null` which results in the empty response you see.

Change the controller to:

```
@RestController
public class MonthlyExpensesController {

    @GetMapping("/monthly")
    public Expenses getMonthlyExpenses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it works as it should.

One more thing: Please in future use minimal, compilable examples, I first had to setup a dummy database to get the program running.

**Update:**

Besides changing the controller so that the css file will be served, you need to fix the code to load the stylesheet. You have to change

```
<link type ="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

otherwise the file is not interpreted as a css file. The login page then looks like this when I run it:

[image: login screen]

Personally, I would move the lines loading the css files from the end of the page into the `<head>` section, that prevents the unstyled page being displayed until the css are loaded.

Comment: Hi, I modified the controller as you said (I also updated the project in github as you can see) but the error still there. I noticed that if I go to localhost:8080/css/style.css it shows the file. I also tried to remove the controller MonthlyExpenses but it doesn't work

Comment: check my updated answer, there are errors in the statements including the css file

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
since you are using Thymeleaf you can use that to fetch the resource.

```
<link type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"
      th:href="@{css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```